# (Unity2D) Как сделать вылезающего врага

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я новичок в unity. Сейчас делаю 2D игру и хотел бы добавить туда врага, который вылезает из земли через равные промежутки времени и залезает обратно. Что-то типа цветочка из марио. Хотелось бы чтобы он имел возможность вылезать со всех сторон, и снизу, и сверху, и слева, и справа. Буду рад любой помощи
[image: Пример]

Answer (score 1):

Всё решается с помощью оси Z. Спрайт врага находится за спрайтом ограждения. Например, ограда по Z на 0, а враг на -5. Вылезание это изменение координат врага. Тут уж как вы захотите - хоть вверх, хоть вниз, хоть по диагонали. Вас в этом ничто не ограничивает.

```
gameObject_enemy.transform.position = new Vector3(20f, 10f, -5);
```

Comment: Не думаю что мне это подходит. Я бы хотел написать код, который будет плавно выдвигать врага из под земли, где он ни находился, а ваш код просто перемещает его в указанную точку. Я так полагаю мне нужно использовать, либо Lerp, либо MoveTowards, но я не знаю как ограничить движение, ибо при помещении этого в Update, враг просто движется вперед без остановок.